# How to replace an HOC that strips props and assigns classnames with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

right now i have a higher-order-component that allows me juice up any component, it:

- allows component it to take a `color` prop
- passes the component a className with the color's css class
- doesn't pass the color prop down to the component

it looks like this:

```
// withColor.js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './withColor.css'
import cn from 'classnames'

const withColor = TargetComponent => {
  const WrappedComponent = props => {
    // color is something like "black" or "red" and has a matching css class
    const { className, color, ...rest } = props
    const enhancedClassName = cn(className, {
      [styles[`Color-${color}`]]: color,
    })
    return <TargetComponent className={enhancedClassName} {...rest} />
  }
  return WrappedComponent
}
```

example usage:

```
// box.js
import React from 'react'
import withColor from '../hocs/withColor'

const Box = props => <div data-box {...props} />

export default withColor(Box)
```

can i use react hooks to do this instead? what would it look like?

Comment: check https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to write a custom hook that performs the above logic. Infact its not even a hook but a common function

```
const useWithColor = (props) => {
   const { className, color, ...rest } = props
    const enhancedClassName = cn(className, {
      [styles[`Color-${color}`]]: color,
    })
   return {...rest, enhancedClassName};
}
```

and use it like

```
export default props =>  {
   const dataProps = useWithColor(props);
   return <div data-box {...dataProps} />
}
```